# Why can't I import android.os.StrictMode?

Tags: java, android, android-strictmode

Why I am facing error at the import android.os.StrictMode?

```
import android.os.StrictMode; 

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
--->StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
```

I have tried to implement a strictmode.java class. [strictmode.java taken from here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/os/StrictMode.java). However, I am facing the imports errors of this.

```
import android.app.ActivityManagerNative;
import android.app.ApplicationErrorReport;
import com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit;
import dalvik.system.BlockGuard;
```

What should I do? Or is there another way to implement in this? I have to implement this in order to run my application on Android 3.0.

Comment: What does the error message say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`StrictMode` is available since API level 9.

So make sure your build target is at least API level 9 (Android 2.3.1).

Comment: Ohh okay! manage to solve it. I just have to change the build target

Comment: If i just put this code under all activity will it work? Going to run on android 3.1.`public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
--->StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);`